# Installing cudatoolkit works with conda install but not with conda create -f

Tags: pytorch, conda

I have a PyTorch environment file:

```
name: torch
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=3.7
  - pytorch::pytorch
  - pytorch::torchvision
  - pytorch::torchaudio
  - pytorch::cudatoolkit
  - numpy
  - scipy
  - scikit-learn
  - matplotlib
  - pillow
  - tqdm
  - joblib
  - visdom
  - jsonpatch
  - pip
  - pip:
    - torchsummary
    - opencv-python==4.1.1.26
```

Trying to create a conda environment from it with `conda create -f torch.yml` fails:

```
(base) prompt@PC:~$ conda env create -f environment.yml 
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound: 
  - pytorch::cudatoolkit
```

The environment is created without issues if I remove `cudatoolkit` from the list of dependencies.

However, `conda install cudatoolkit -c pytorch` finds and installs the package without issues. The same happens if I replace `cudatoolkit` with `cudatoolkit=11.3` (the current most recent version listed on the PyTorch website) in both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue by installing `cudatoolkit` from the `nvidia` channel, rather than `pytorch`. I'm still not sure why `cudatoolkit` is available from `pytorch` with one method but not the other, but this solves my issue (although the `nvidia` version seems to be larger, so it's probably a superset package of `pytorch`'s `cudatoolkit`). My YAML file now looks like this:

```
name: ritnet
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=3.7
  - pytorch::pytorch
  - pytorch::torchvision
  - pytorch::torchaudio
  - nvidia::cudatoolkit=11.3
  - numpy
  - scipy
  - scikit-learn
  - matplotlib
  - pillow
  - tqdm
  - joblib
  - visdom
  - jsonpatch
  - pip
  - pip:
    - torchsummary
    - opencv-python==4.1.1.26
```

Answer (score 0):

You have that error because there is no package called `pytorch::cudatoolkit` found by conda.

You yml env file have to look like this:

```yaml
name: torch
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
  - pytorch
dependencies:
  - python=3.7
  - pytorch
  - torchvision
  - torchaudio
  - cudatoolkit=11.3
  - numpy
  - scipy
  - scikit-learn
  - matplotlib
  - pillow
  - tqdm
  - joblib
  - visdom
  - jsonpatch
  - pip
  - pip:
    - torchsummary
    - opencv-python==4.1.1.26
```

Comment: This installs an old version of `pytorch` from the `defaults` channel, which is not what I want. It also probably works differently depending on the conda channel priority configuration of the machine it's run on. Also, conda is not looking for a package called `pytorch::cudatoolkit`, it's looking for a package called `cudatoolkit` in the channel `pytorch`, which apparently does not exist. The question I'm asking is why the package is then found with `conda install cudatoolkit -c pytorch`.